# Angular 2 attribute and *ngIf

Tags: angular

What is incorrect? I want to show this attribute if error how to make it right?

```html
<label for="email" *ngIf="(form.controls.email.errors && form.controls.email.dirty) ? true : [attr.data-error]="wrong" ">E-Mail</label>
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" formControlName="email">
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<label for="email" [attr.data-error]="(form.controls.email.errors && form.controls.email.dirty)? 'wrong': null">E-Mail</label>
```